# Best practice for Java EE application development using extjs and Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs4.1, sencha-architect

I am a newbie to extjs and kind of new to javascript world also. I have developed applications in jsp/servlet, JSF etc.
We are planning to use extjs along with Sencha Architect to develop UIs for our application. 
Being new I have several questions for which I am searching answers

Q1. How should we use Sencha Architect in multi developer environment in terms of versioning. Shall we checkin the Architect project into svn and ask each developer to work on same project.

Q2. What should be the structure of Sencha Architect project (Basically how to make sure each developer is working on his/her individual module without affecting others component).
Is there any best practice for this.

Q3. What is the best practice for developing an application which contains several pages along with navigation. Should we create a single html file (with lot of javascript to modify the body) or should we have multiple html?

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, it should certainly be in source control. you will want developer-specific settings to not be in source control however.
2. the best way is to create an application "shell" with menu bars, and load in modules/plugins and have them register with the application, adding their own menus etc.
3. definitely a single page application. security remains on the server though (for example in your REST API). security is irrelevant on the client as they have control over source code. you should just hide functionality that a user should not use.

[How to load different views into viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120226/load-different-views-into-viewport/11120496#11120496)